# Is it possible to "find" an aura:id within an aura:id?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, javascript-controller, aura-iteration

I have a component where I am building a `lightning:recordEditForm` using fields based on a different field sets that looks a little something like this:

```
<aura:component>

    <aura:attribute name="fieldApiNames" type="List" />
    <aura:attribute name="showSpinner" type="Boolean" default="true" />

    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.showSpinner}">
        <lightning:spinner alternativeText="Loading..." />
    </aura:if>

    <lightning:recordEditForm onload="{!c.handleLoad}" objectApiName="Account">
        <lightning:messages />

        <lightning:layout multipleRows="true">
            <aura:iteration items="{!v.fieldApiNames}" var="api">
                <lightning:layoutItem aura:id="formItems" size="6">
                    <div aura:id="top-div" />
                    <lightning:inputField aura:id="field" fieldName="{!api}" />
                    <div aura:id="bottom-div" />
                </lightning:layoutItem>
            </aura:iteration>
        </lightning:layout>
    </lightning:recordEditForm>

    <lightning:button title="Show Field Values" onclick="{!c.handleButton}" />

</aura:component>
```

When you call `find()` on an `aura:id` that occurs multiple times, you get back an array of everything with that `aura:id`. If I wanted to access an element within the body of one of the elements returned with my `find()` call, could I do it with the `aura:id` of said sub-element like below, in the `handleButton` function?

```
({
    handleLoad : function(cmp, evt, helper) {
        cmp.set( "v.showSpinner", false );
    },

    handleButton : function(cmp, evt, helper) {
        var first = cmp.get("v.fieldApiNames")[0];
        cmp.find("formItems").forEach( function(item) {
            alert( item.find("field").get("v.value") );       <== ?
        } );
    }
})
```

Comment: Something like  `cmp.find("formItems").find("field").get("v.value");` ?

Comment: That particular line throws an error, because (.. I think ..) I need to use the loop on `cmp.find("formItems")` because there will be multiple elements with that `aura:id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that this "nested find" (per se) is not possible. I opted to dynamically create each `lightning:layoutItem` and each, respectively, nested `lightning:inputField` in an `init` handler for my component. This allowed me to assign an `aura:id` as I created each individual component.

Answer (score 0):

you should use `foreach` for `lightning:inputField` aura id, then you get array of inputfields cmps then do foreach and get values like what i tried below

**controller.js**

```
 handleButton : function(cmp, evt, helper) {
        var first = cmp.get("v.fieldApiNames")[0];
        cmp.find("field").forEach( function(itemcmp) {
            alert( itemcmp.get("v.value") );       <== ?
        } );
    }
```

Comment: This would work in scenarios where the use case is exactly the same as my example. Unfortunately (and I apologize if this was poor practice), my example is not my exact use case. I was trying to simplify it to find a answer without too much of the nitty gritty.